# jQuery selector chaining

Tags: jquery, checkbox, css-selectors

We're having an issue trying to chain selectors together. We are trying to get all checkboxes that are checked and have the data-action attribute with hideplan as the value. I've got a page that has two checkboxes, one button and this javascript on it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var hiddenplans = $('input:checkbox[data-action="hideplan":checked');
    $("#hide_btn").click(function() {
        hiddenplans.each(

        function(index) {
            alert('checked' + index);
        });
    });​ 
</script>
```

This doesn't display any alerts when one or more checkboxes are selected - hiddenplans is empty. However, if we copy `$('input:checkbox[data-action="hideplan":checked');` and put it into the firebug console and run it we will get results if one or more checkboxes are selected. If I remove :checked it will alert for checkboxes with data-action=hideplan.

We've tried several different ways of writing the selector (i.e. `$("input[type=checkbox][data-action=hideplan]:checked")` and `$("input[type=checkbox][data-action=hideplan]").filter(":checked");` and more) and they work in the console but will not return alerts.

I've created a Fiddle with the full code in case we missed something obvious http://jsfiddle.net/xCnSs/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're caching the selected set in a variable so it will only return which items are checked on page load.  Move this selector into your click function and it will work:

```
$("#hide_btn").click(function () {
    var hiddenplans = $("input[type=checkbox][data-action=hideplan]:checked");
    hiddenplans.each(function (index) {
        alert('checked' + index);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xCnSs/6/

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
$('input:checkbox[data-action="hideplan"]:checked')
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/nY72j/).

Comment: Remember to use a tag before most pseudo-selectors, otherwise a universal selector `*` is implied and will need to test *every* element on the page. :o) From the docs: *"As with other pseudo-class selectors (those that begin with a ":") it is recommended to precede it with a tag name or some other selector; otherwise, the universal selector ("\*") is implied."*

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the closing bracket:

```
$('input:checkbox[data-action="hideplan"]:checked');
```

But remember you can also filter results:

```
$('input:checkbox[data-action="hideplan"]').filter(':checked');
```

Comment: just a typo. didnt fix the issue. issue was pointed out by mVChr